# How to change the text of a button in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do you change the text value of a button in jQuery? Currently, my button has 'Add' as its text value, and upon being clicked I want it to change to 'Save'. I have tried this method below, but so far without success:

```
$("#btnAddProfile").attr('value', 'Save');
```

Comment: actually your example should work to change the value of the button. I tried it and it worked. Maybe the id of the button is different or a typo.

Comment: Still doesn't work...could JQuery UI styles be causing this?

Comment: Sergey's answer was best. it is working properly on jquery buttons without removing its styles, padding and margins.

Answer (score 1041, accepted):

Depends on what type of button you are using

```
<input type='button' value='Add' id='btnAddProfile'>
$("#btnAddProfile").attr('value', 'Save'); //versions older than 1.6

<input type='button' value='Add' id='btnAddProfile'>
$("#btnAddProfile").prop('value', 'Save'); //versions newer than 1.6

<!-- Different button types-->

<button id='btnAddProfile' type='button'>Add</button>
$("#btnAddProfile").html('Save');
```

Your button could also be a link. You'll need to post some HTML for a more specific answer.

**EDIT** : These will work assuming you've wrapped it in a `.click()` call, of course

**EDIT 2** : Newer jQuery versions (from > 1.6) use `.prop` rather than `.attr`

**EDIT 3** : If you're using jQuery UI, you need to use DaveUK's method ([below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755696/295508)) of adjusting the text property

Comment: Got it working using .html('Save'), I didn't notice that I had set runat=server on my button, this is what was causing the issue.

Comment: I would downvote this if I could, as it messes up the style in some cases. *Please use the answer of DaveUK, if you have trouble with this one*. PS: I guess that's what Sevenearths noticed, too

Comment: Even better: use the answer from Sergey below for proper use of jQuery and future-proofing: $( ".selector" ).button( "option", "label", "new text" );

Comment: For `button` elements, you can also use `$("#element").val("New Label");`

Answer (score 161):

For buttons created with .Button() in jQuery........

Whilst the other answers will change the text they will mess up the styling of the button, it turns out that when a jQuery button is rendered the text of the button is nested within a span e.g.

```
<button id="thebutton">
  <span class="ui-button-text">My Text</span>
</button>
```

If you remove the span and replace it with text (as in the other examples) - you'll loose the span and associated formatting.

So you actually need to change the text within the SPAN tag and NOT the BUTTON!

```
$("#thebutton span").text("My NEW Text");
```

or (if like me it's being done on a click event)

```
$("span", this).text("My NEW Text");
```

Comment: You shouldn't be expecting this DOM structure to never change. Far better is to use the method jQuery-UI gives you to change the label (see Sergey's answer).

Answer (score 84):

The correct way of changing the button text if it was "buttonized" using JQuery is to use .button() method:

```
$( ".selector" ).button( "option", "label", "new text" );
```

Comment: This worked for me better than the other approaches, which stomped on the styling of the button (in particular the size of the button).  I was using a button on a jQuery UI dialog, FWIW.

Comment: This is the correct answer for buttons created with jQuery, such as those on a dialog.  All the others will destroy some of the jQuery styling.  This also does it without depending on the HTML structure that jQuery generates, which is more future-proof.

Comment: This is the right answer to this question (it seems the question is about Jquery UI buttons, see comments), it should be promoted.

Answer (score 41):

To change the text in of a button simply execute the following line of jQuery
for

`<input type='button' value='XYZ' id='btnAddProfile'>`

use

```
$("#btnAddProfile").val('Save');
```

while for

`<button id='btnAddProfile'>XYZ</button>`

use this

`$("#btnAddProfile").html('Save');`

Comment: Also, for buttons created by jquery using e.g. `$('#thing').append($("<button />")....)`, you need to use .html to set the text.

Answer (score 32):

Use `.val()`

[Here's a link to JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYA6q/)

Answer (score 24):

You can use something like this:

```
$('#your-button').text('New Value');
```

You can also add extra properties like this:

```
$(this).text('New Value').attr('disabled', true).addClass('bt-hud').unbind('click');
```

Comment: Doesn't work input buttons or submit buttons, use  val()

Answer (score 23):

You need to do `.button("refresh")`

**HTML** :

```
<button id='btnviewdetails' type='button'>SET</button>
```

**JS** :

```
$('#btnviewdetails').text('Save').button("refresh");
```

Comment: For some reason, it would only work for me after I used your code to refresh the button, but I also noticed that the icon on the button (part of JQuery Mobile CSS) gets lost after refreshing it (although your solution was by the closest I got).

Answer (score 14):

`$("#btnAddProfile").text("Save");`

Answer (score 12):

If you have button'ed your button this seems to work:

```
<button id="button">First caption</button>

$('#button').button();//make it nice
var text="new caption";
$('#button').children().first().html(text);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
$("#btnAddProfile").text('Save');
```

although

```
$("#btnAddProfile").html('Save');
```

would work as well, but it's misleading (it gives the impression you could write something like

```
$("#btnAddProfile").html('Save <b>now</b>');
```

but of course you can't

Answer (score 6):

it's work for me
html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSaveSchedule">abc</button>
```

js

```
$("#btnSaveSchedule").text("new value");
```

Comment: This worked for a bootstrap 4 styled button - using jquery 3.6.1

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#btnAddProfile").click(function(){
    $("#btnAddProfile").attr('value', 'Save');
 });
```

Comment: Repeating the non-working code from the question is not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('btnAddProfile').value='Save';
```

Comment: Unhelpful, OP asked for jQuery

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();

    if (this.value=="Add") this.value = "Save";
    else this.value = "Add";

  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type='button' value='Add' id='btnAddProfile'>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you gave your button a class instead of an id? try the following code

```
$(".btnSave").attr('value', 'Save');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnviewdetails").click(function(){
    if($(this).val()!="hide details"){
        $("#detailedoutput").show();
        $(this).val('hide details');
    }else{
        $("#detailedoutput").hide();
        $(this).val('view more details');
    }

});
```

Comment: Include some details about your answer.

Comment: please include details with your answer. I have no clue what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#btnAddProfile").prop('value', 'Save');       
$("#btnAddProfile").button('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btnAddProfile").html('Save').button('refresh');
```

Answer (score -1):

that's exactly correct, this works for me;

```
    $('#btnAddProfile').bind('click',function(){
    $(this).attr('value','save');
})
```

are you sure Jquery is available and that your code is in the correct place?

Answer (score -1):

```
    $( "#btnAddProfile" ).on( "click",function(event){
    $( event.target ).html( "Save" );
});
```