# Tapestry5 Button Appearance

Tags: tapestry

In tapestry5 is possible to change a submit button text?

In jquery is possible as is indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text). But using java methods, how is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

henning's answer is spot on, however if you indeed want to use "java methods" you can use the `prop` binding prefix like so:

in your tml:

`<input type="submit" t:type="submit" t:value="prop:submitText" />`

in your java:

```
public String getSubmitText()
{
    return "Submit me!";
}
```

[Using Binding Expressions](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-parameters.html#ComponentParameters-UsingBindingExpressions)

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can! Just use the same `value` attribute in your TML that you would in plain HTML:

```
<input type="submit" t:type="Submit" value="Submit me!" />
```

Check the [`Submit` component reference](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Submit.html) for further options.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it using Tapestry5-jquery button mixin:

In tml:

```
<input t:type="submit" t:id="nextBtn" t:mixins="jquery/button" t:params="nextButtonParams" />
```

In java:

```
public JSONObject getNextButtonParams(){
    String label = "Next";
    if(userIndex == selectedUsers.size() - 1)
        label = "Finish";

    return new JSONObject("label", label);
}
```