# jquery prop multiple items?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong but for the past 2 hours I've been trying to use prop to change the value of two items in a button. It works for one but not for the other and I have no idea why.

html:

```
<input type='button' value='Following' id='btnFollow' dataaction="UnFollow" datatype='topic'>
```

jquery:

```
    $("#btnFollow").prop("value", "Follow");
    $("#btnFollow").prop("dataaction", "Follow");
```

The first item changes(`value`) but not the second one(`dataaction`).  I have no idea why(other then maybe its too late and my brain is rebelling).  According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) I'm doing it correct.  I added alerts inbetween each command in case one was failing, but both alerts went off meaning jquery is not crashing or anything when it tries to change the second item. I don't see any spelling mistakes and I tried to daisy chain the commands but still no luck.

Any suggestions?

entire_code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnFollow').click(function() {
        var topic_id = $(this).attr('datatopic');
        var action_type = $(this).attr('datatype');
        var action_type_action = $(this).attr('dataaction');
        alert(action_type_action);
        //$("#btnFollow").prop('value', 'Following');
        if (action_type_action == 'Follow') {
            $("#btnFollow").prop({'value': 'Following', 'dataaction': 'UnFollow'});
            //$("#btnFollow").prop("value", "Following");
            //$("#btnFollow").prop("dataaction", "UnFollow");
                 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/follow_modification',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    topic: topic_id,
                    action: action_type_action,
                    follow_type: action_type
                }
                //complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
                //    ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
                //}
            });

        } else if (action_type_action == 'UnFollow') {
            $("#btnFollow").prop({'value': 'Follow', 'dataaction': 'Follow'});
            //$("#btnFollow").prop("value", "Follow");
            //$("#btnFollow").prop("dataaction", "Follow");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/follow_modification',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    topic: topic_id,
                    action: action_type_action,
                    follow_type: action_type
                }
                //complete: function(xmlRequestObject, successString){
                //    ymmReceiveAjaxResponse(xmlRequestObject, successString);
                //}
            });
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: @AnkitGautam I thought with the newer jquery your suppose to use prop to change values?

Comment: Your code works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/Capvk/

Comment: Have you tried `$('#btnFollow').prop({'value': 'Follow', 'dataaction': 'Follow'});`?

Comment: as a side note, data attributes are hyphenated. `data-action`

Comment: @zerkms using chrome's inspect element function, I don't see the dataaction changing on my site as well as the jsfiddle you posted.

Comment: I just posted the full code in case there's another part causing the problem

Comment: @Lostsoul: there is no another problem. Have you checked the answers? ;-) PS: why do you use `.prop()` to set value and `.attr()` to get it?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/Capvk/

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

So that's why you don't see it changed in html, but it is changed in DOM instead. If you want it to be changed in HTML as well - use `.attr()`

PS: as @ahren mentioned in the comments - it probably makes sense to use `.data()` and `data-xxx` properties

PPS: if you set the value using `.prop()` - you need to get it with `.prop()` respectively

Comment: Thanks so much it worked!!  I used to use attr but I remember reading that if you use jquery 1.6+ you should be using prop..Is that true or is it safe to use attr?  My logic was if I am going to learn something I might as well learn what's encouraged to be used.  p.s. I changed the names back..thanks!

Comment: Here's the answer that got me thinking I shouldn't use attr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text

Answer (score 9):

If there is a need to set multiple properties with single jQuery `.prop` method,
just try this:

instead

```
$("#btnFollow").prop("value", "Follow");
$("#btnFollow").prop("dataaction", "Follow");
```

use

```
$("#btnFollow").prop({"value": "Follow", "dataaction": "Follow"});
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use `.attr` jQuery method.

Please use properly html5 data attribute as`enter code here` data-action for which you have new jQuery method to access this data attribute with `$('#btnFollow').data('action')` For more details [visit](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

Comment: Regarding `.data()`, note that the OP is trying to set properties of the element and `.data()` doesn't do that (even though it can _retrieve_ `data-xyz` attribute values).