# Change the value of a button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with the value 'Browser for files', when you select a file, the value should change to the file name.
The text of the button doesn't change, it's still 'Browse for files' but it should change to the file name.

```
<input style="display: none" id="file-type" type="file" size="4" name="file"/>
<input id="browse-click" type="button" class="button2" value="Browse for files!"/>
```

script

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var intervalFunc = function () {
        $('#browse-click').html($('#file-type').val());
    };
    $('#browse-click').on('click', function () {
        $('#file-type').click();
        setInterval(intervalFunc, 1);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Fixed script:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var intervalFunc = function () {
        $("#browse-click").prop('value', $('#file-type').val());
    };
    $('#browse-click').on('click', function () {
        $('#file-type').click();
        setInterval(intervalFunc, 1);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: And your question is? edit: _Make flying monkeys fall from the sky_ I LOL'd

Comment: Perhaps he doesn't like waffles :(

Comment: The text of the button doesn't change, it's still 'Browse for files!' but it should change to the file name

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5580652/1850609

Comment: @Luxie you mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kgxPF/1/)?

Comment: [This](http://tmphost.tk/upload) is how it looks now! thanks
PS: It's not spam, it's only how works now.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#file-type').change(function(){
        $('#browse-click').val($(this).val());
    });
    $('#browse-click').on('click', function () {
        $('#file-type').click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already fixed this. I added the working script to the description.