# change text on link when div is open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on my page

```
 <button id="show1" class="morelinkblack">Find Out More</button>
```

When clicked it runs this code

```
 $("#show1").click(function(){
   $(".hidden-div1").slideToggle("slow");
 });
```

Is there a way of changing the text to say "Close" instead of "find out more" while the div is visible?

Comment: `if($("#show1").is(":visible")) { //change text}`

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text

Comment: @yogesh that seems too different for me to compare but thank you for the response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
$("#show1").click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    $(".hidden-div1").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            that.text("Close");
        } else {
            that.text("Find out more");
        }
    });
});
```

Based on the comments, the div could be opened or closed depending on where the user is directed from. A simple check in the DOM ready can set the text accordingly:

```
$(".hidden-div1").is(":visible") ? $("#show1").text("Close") : $("#show1").text("Find out more");
```

Comment: fantastic but when the page loads with the div open already it doesnt work properly.  It starts with the find out more text

Comment: If the default div is set to open, then set the default text to "Close"

Comment: it all depends on where they come from and what they are looking for.  I need it to swing both ways.  Thats why im finding it so hard I think.  Yours is perfect until the page is loaded with the div open

Comment: On page load, run a check, I'll update my answer to accomodate this.

Comment: thank you for your time you have saved my life there.  Thought I was stuck forever!!  Works like a dream!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Updated code

```
$("#show1").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    $(".hidden-div1").slideToggle("slow", function() {
        if ($(this).css('display') == 'none') { // <- Updated here to check if div is close or open
            el.text('Find Out More');
        } else {
            el.text('Hide More');
        }
    });
});
```

Update button text on document ready / page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".hidden-div1").css('display') == 'none') {
        $("#show1").text('Find Out More');
    } else {
        $("#show1").text('Hide More');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yours also works great but the page can be loaded with the div open.  When this happens the text is the wrong way around.  If the page is loaded with the div close the text is perfect

Comment: In that case we can check `$(this).css('display')` before updating button text. Code updated.

Comment: Code updated. Now button text update on document ready / page load

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this :

```
$("#show1").click(function () {
    var $div = $(this);
    $(".hidden-div1").slideToggle("slow").promise().done(function () {
        $div.text(function () {
            return $(this).is(":visible") ? "Close" : "Find Out More"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response.  No that just loads with the find out more link still with find out more written.  When clicked it shows the close link then doesn't change