# why is jQuery not changing the text of my button?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using jQuery with the colorbox plugin. I want to change the text of a button w/ jquery. Following this example, [jQuery change button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text) I added this line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#cboxClose').html('Hello World');
```

But the text of the button still says "Close"

Jfiddle shows that my code should work: http://jsfiddle.net/wTwXz/ -- but the console does not show any errors. Changing the code to `.val("hello world")` or `.text("hello world")` both don't work. Also, the HTML that shown in firebug shows that there is no other element with id=cboxclose

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<div style="display:none">
<div id="cboxOverlay" style="opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer; visibility: visible;"></div>
<div id="colorbox" class="" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; visibility: visible; top: 421px; left: 588px; position: absolute; width: 504px; height: 104px;">
<div id="cboxWrapper" style="height: 104px; width: 504px;">
<div>
<div style="clear: left;">
<div id="cboxMiddleLeft" style="float: left; height: 62px;"></div>
<div id="cboxContent" style="float: left; width: 462px; height: 62px;">
<div id="cboxLoadedContent" style="width: 462px; overflow: auto; height: 34px;">
<div id="cboxTitle" style="float: left; display: block;"></div>
<div id="cboxCurrent" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<button id="cboxPrevious" type="button" style="display: none;"></button>
<button id="cboxNext" type="button" style="display: none;"></button>
<button id="cboxSlideshow" style="display: none;"></button>
<div id="cboxLoadingOverlay" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<div id="cboxLoadingGraphic" style="float: left; display: none;"></div>
<button id="cboxClose" type="button">close</button>
</div>
<div id="cboxMiddleRight" style="float: left; height: 62px;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 9999px; visibility: hidden; display: none;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What else can I try?

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/wTwXz/ check the console for an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Check if same id used for some other element in the same page.

Comment: maybe you could try `val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unexpected behavior comes from the order of the jQuery calls within color box that create the alert panel. If I add the code in an onComplete function that fires once color box finishes making the box, then everything works fine.

```
$.colorbox({width:"30%", inline:true, href:"#inline_content",
                    onComplete: function() {
                    $('#cboxClose').text('Hello World');
                 },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#cboxClose').text('Hello World');`

Answer (score 0):

If you use .val() it works fine

```
<input id="cboxClose" type="button" value="Close"></input>

$(document).ready(function(){
            //Examples of how to assign the Colorbox event to elements
            $('#cboxClose').val('Hello World');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Develop_er/NzVxK/1/