# Change button text

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I've found part of my answer on :[jQuery change button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text)

to change the text of a button on the click.  What I'm searching for is how to toggle that text.  I've tried using the class method to toggle the text of "show teams" / "hide teams".
If I just use the property I can change the text on the button click but that will not change it back.

HTML

```
<input class="teams" type="button" value="Teams" />
```

js

```
    $(".teams").click(function () {
        $("#container2").toggle();
        //$("#teams").prop("value", "Hide Teams");

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass('teams')) {
            $this.text('Show Teams');
        } else {
            $this.text('Hide Teams');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` elements do not have text content

Quoting the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

> Get the combined **text contents** of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

---

Either use a `button` tag

```
<button class="teams">Teams</button>
```

or use the `.val()` method (*that applies to input elements*) instead of the `.text()`

Now since you test for the existence of the `teams` class you will need to also toggle that

```
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('teams')) {
        $this.text('Show Teams');
    } else {
        $this.text('Hide Teams');
    }
    $this.toggleClass('teams'); // add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(".teams").click(function () {
        $("#container2").toggle();
        //$("#teams").prop("value", "Hide Teams");

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.val() === 'Show Teams') {
            $this.val('Hide Teams');
        } else {
            $this.val('Show Teams');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the attribute `value` to your text: `$this.attr('value', 'Show Teams');`

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qMrbn/