# Button Text Does Not Change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I have been messing around with this for a few hours now and decided to ask. I have searched StackOverflow and Google, with no resolution. I am trying to change the text of a button, like below.

```
<input id="btnRegUpdate" type="submit"  onclick="updatePrice(1)" value="Correct">
```

The `updatePrice()` function is called and checks a few things and at the end I have an if statement that checks the value to see if it is Correct, if it is, it will change the text, or suppose to.

```
var btnRegUpdate = $('#btnRegUpdate');

if (btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Correct'){
    logMessage("Button was correct");
    btnRegUpdate.text("Update");
}
```

At this point I have tried everything in this solution [jQuery change button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text) with nothing working. I get the logMessage, but the button still doesn't change.

**UPDATE:** Nothing seems to be working. I tried everything again in a new function, just in case the other logic was messing with something. After doing a quick test to see if the text was change

```
function updatePrice2(val, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btnRegUpdate = $('#btnRegUpdate');

    if (btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Correct') {
        logMessage("Button was correct");
        btnRegUpdate.val("Update");
    }else if(btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Update'){
        logMessage('Button was update');
        btnRegUpdate.val("Correct");
    }
}
```

and the console shows that it changed but doesn't on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the innerHTML not the text. Like so:

```
btnRegUpdate.html("Update");
```

EDIT:

Just noticed you're using a `<input>` not a `<button>`, change the value property:

```
btnRegUpdate.attr('value', 'Update');
```

Comment: You answer ultimately resolved the issue. I change my `<input>` to a `<button>` and then used `.html` to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
btnRegUpdate.attr("value", "Update")
```

instead of

```
btnRegUpdate.text("Update");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var btnRegUpdate = $('#btnRegUpdate');
if (btnRegUpdate.val() == 'Correct'){
    btnRegUpdate.attr('Value',"Update");
}
```

Try using `btnRegUpdate.attr('Value',"Update");`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x4uL50b4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> **Prevent default action of submit button**
>
> **Change the value of button using `val()`**

```js
function updatePrice(val, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var btnRegUpdate = $('#btnRegUpdate');

  if (btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Correct') {
    console.log("Button was correct");
    btnRegUpdate.val("Update");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="btnRegUpdate" type="submit" onclick="updatePrice(1,event)" value="Correct">
```

Answer (score 0):

The input element's text is defined by its value attribute, not content. To change the text, update the value attribute:

```
btnRegUpdate.attr('value', "Update");
```

instead of

```
btnRegUpdate.text("Update");
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use .html() to change the contents. It works the same as javascript's .innerHtml

```
var btnRegUpdate = $('#btnRegUpdate');

if (btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Correct'){
    logMessage("Button was correct");
    btnRegUpdate.html('Update')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false` to the click handler.

```
<input id="btnRegUpdate" type="submit"  onclick="updatePrice(1); return false;" value="Correct">
```

Otherwise the page will attempt to submit and reload.

Answer (score 0):

Your function look good and i don't know it's not working.

```
function updatePrice2(val, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var btnRegUpdate = $('#btnRegUpdate');

    if (btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Correct') {
        logMessage("Button was correct");
        btnRegUpdate.val("Update");
    }else if(btnRegUpdate.attr('value') == 'Update'){
        logMessage('Button was update');
        btnRegUpdate.val("Correct");
    }
}
```

I suggest you check in your page and find id "btnRegUpdate", maybe it appear more than one.