# Implementing AJAX into a rails form.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a from in which a user can send out a message via SMS. The form functions with the capability of scheduling out a message. Right now I have a static button that says "send message" and it works but when a user schedules a message I'd like the button to switch the inside text to read "schedule message" by an onlcick type action. I think this should be an esay thing to implement using ajax but I've never used it before in a rails app. I'll show a screen shot and some code, hopefully this will be enough info. let me know if you need anymore provided code than I initially show.

Here is my form screenshot, so when a user clicks on the calender glyphicon it will initiate the ajax and switch the "Send Message" button to say "Schedule Message" 
[image]

Here is the code for my form

```
<div class="container text-center">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 well">
     <%= form_for @message do |form| %>
       <div class="form-group">
         <%= form.label :body, "Enter a Message:", class: "message_label"%>
         <%= form.text_field :body, class: "form-control", placeholder: "New things are happening!" %>
       </div>
       <%= form.submit "Send Message", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
       <h3>Groups:</h3>
       <div class="radio">
         <div class="row col-span10">
           <% Group.all.each do |group| %>
             <div class="col-md-3">
               <label>
                 <input id="message_group_<%= group.id %>" name="message[group_ids][]" value="<%= group.id %>" type="checkbox">
                 <%= group.name %>
               </label>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3>Scheduled Text Message:</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4'>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
              <%= form.text_field :send_at, class: "form-control" %>
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you don't need an ajax call for simply changing the button text. Have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5580652/2968762) if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to read [Working with javascript in Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for), there it explain several things about javascript and AJAX.

Basically, you need to tag your form as `remote` and hook with javascript to AJAX events (success, complete, error, etc) to perform any animation/transition you want.

Comment: Thanks! anyway you could code an example for my situation I'm having trouble understanding some of the tuts.