# how to change button text after succes in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to change button text on success.. I want to change this to accepted after success

```
    <button type="button" onclick="saveData<?php echo $row1->id; ?>()">Accept</button> 
      <script>
      function saveData<?php echo $rrr->id; ?>(){

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/accept_seller/'. $rrr->id; ?>",
        data:{},       
        success:function( data )
        {

        }
       });
  }
```

My function is properly working because i have used alert after success but i dontknow how to chage its text after success. pls help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery change button text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text)

Answer (score 3):

You can associate a class with the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick=".." class="submit-btn">Accept</button>
```

Now, in your AJAX success code, mention the following:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/accept_seller/'. $rrr->id; ?>",
    data:{},       
    success:function( data ) {
       $(".submit-btn").html("Accepted");   // Add this line
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a typo, should be $(".submit-btn").html("Accepted");

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. :) I've made the necessary modifications.

Comment: Thank you Object Manipulator and Tom ... its working

Comment: what if i want to pass this row id ($rrr->id;) with class submit-btn... because if i click accept on one row then it change to accepted in all rows ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/accept_seller/'. $rrr->id; ?>",
  data: {},
  success: function(data) {
   $("#btn").text('your new text here'); // add id to your button
  }
});

<button id="btn" type="button" onclick="saveData<?php echo $row1->id; ?>()">Accept</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) pass `this` in function

2) Use `.text()` function to change text of button.

```
<button type="button" onclick="saveData<?php echo $row1->id; ?>(this)">Accept</button> 
<script>
          function saveData<?php echo $rrr->id; ?>(obj){
              $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/accept_seller/'. $rrr->id; ?>",
                 data:{},       
                 success:function( data )
                 {
                      $(obj).text("New Text");
                 }
              });
          }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML : add id in button

```
<button type="button" id="accept" onclick="saveData<?php echo $row1->id; ?>()">Accept</button>
```

script:

```
 success:function( data ) {
       $("#accept").html("accepted");   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

id; ?>()">Accept 
      
      function saveDataid; ?>(){

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url().'home/accept_seller/'. $rrr->id; ?>",
    data:{},       
    success:function( data )
    {
       $("#buttonid").html('Changetext');
    }
   });
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. When answering a question that already has many answers, please be sure to add some additional insight into why the response you're providing is substantive and not simply echoing what's already been vetted by the original poster. This is especially important in "code-only" answers such as the one you've provided.