# ajax success function cant change button text

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a simple but strange question, I am not able to change the value of the button in an ajax post success callback, I am sure the callback gets executed as the alert was shown. Also, those buttons are created statically, I did not create them dynamically using Jquery.

Below is my ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    url: "/?handler=Queue",
    data: $.param(params),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#btn-queue-lib").val("Cancel Queue");
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

However, if I change the problem line outside of ajax, it works fine:

```
$("#btn-queue-lib").val("Cancel Queue"); // Either Here
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
    },
    url: "/?handler=Queue",
    data: $.param(params),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
$("#btn-queue-lib").val("Cancel Queue"); // Or Here
```

Comment: Is the AJAX call succeeding?

Comment: @JackBashford Yup, I am sure that the call is succeed as the alert was shown.

Comment: is #btn-queue-lib exists?

Comment: @JasminMistry Yup, as I was able to change its text anywhere outside of the callback using its id.

Comment: Just to be sure, alert of success is called and not error function one?

Comment: @GauravGupta Yup, as I set the success message differ from the error one.

Comment: If you place `console.log($("#btn-queue-lib"))` inside the success callback, what log do you produce on your console? It seems like jQuery can't find any element with that id

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change button text after succes in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374763/how-to-change-button-text-after-succes-in-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

I have found out the problem, I dunno for some reason the server is returning the success message but actually returning a badrequest. Hence I mistaken that the success function should be called. If I put the problem line in the error callback, it works fine. Thanks guys for your efforts !!!
~ (^_^)∠※

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('btn-queue-lib').innerText = 'Cancel Queue'

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$("#btn-queue-lib").val("Cancel Queue");
```

to

```
$("#btn-queue-lib").text("Cancel Queue");
```

and place the statement in ajax success function right before alert.

Comment: Please read comment "Yup, as I was able to change its text anywhere outside of the callback using its id".

Comment: what makes the difference ? outside ajax or inside ajax, button's id is never changing, btw he is using val() instead of text()

Comment: This does not work, and it actually didnt even work outside of the ajax callback also, but the val() works outside.

Answer (score 0):

In Success use

```
 $("#btn-queue-lib").html("Cancel Queue");
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I have faced the same issue... I managed it as below hope it will help for too

```js
function changeAfterAjax(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:"https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
    //data: $.param(params),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        $("#btn-queue-lib").text("Cancel Queue");// this is also works fine 
        //changeBtnTxt('btn-queue-lib','Cancel Queue');
        //alert(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
})
}

function changeBtnTxt(id,txt){
  $("#"+id).text(txt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="changeAfterAjax()" id="btn-queue-lib">Click to chanage after ajax</button>
```