# Can't change the button's value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the value of my button with jQuery.

This is what i have in html:

```
<button id="choice1">John</button>
```

And this is what I've tried to change the value:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        $(this).val("Mike");  
    });
});
```

I even tried `.attr / .prop / .html / .text` 
instead of `.val`
but none of them worked.

Ok so if I'm trying to change it to an Array like this:

```
var a = new Array(4000)

a[2][1] = "North"
a[2][2] = "South"
a[2][3] = "East"
a[2][4] = "West"
```

And the function:

```
function state1gmg(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#gamestatesdiv").text(state1);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#questionsdiv").text(q[1]);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        $(this).html(a[2][1]);  
    });
});
```

}

Any help? Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Make sure jQuery is loaded successfully (check the console).

Comment: Check this out. Well explained. [jQuery change button text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/jquery-change-button-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `text()` or `html()` instead of `val()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        $(this).text("Mike");  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="choice1">John</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing a `<button>` value requires changing `.text` or `.html`.

In this snippet, `.text` works as expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        $(this).text("Mike");  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="choice1">John</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        $(this).val("Mike");  
        console.log ($(this).val()); // Mike. This changes value, but I suppose that you want to change inner text
        $(this).text("Mike");  // now the visible text will be Mike
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="choice1">John</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the value alright, but what you want to do with a button (unlike an input) is to change the HTML (or text):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice1").click(function(){
        $(this).html("Mike");  
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="choice1">John</button>
```

Comment: why html instead of text?

Comment: @qiAlex - No reason at all. As I said in my answer, either works fine. I just had to pick one and both work since a `<button>` can contain both.

Comment: Hmm, Yeah that works fine, but only if I'm changing it to text like "Mike". What if I want to change it to a variable for example?

Comment: @DuarteArribas Then you'd pass `.html()` (or `.text()`) a variable instead of a string. Ex: `$(this).html(myVar)`

Comment: @j08691 Let's say I have an Array. If I did this `$(this).html(a[2][1])` was it suppose to work? Cause it doesn't actually.

Comment: Yes, it should, but you would need to provide a complete code example for us to see where the error is. Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: @j08691 Well It has a couple of errors that i might need help figuring them out. So first the arrays are `var a = new Array(4000)

a[2][1] = "North"
a[2][2] = "South"
a[2][3] = "East"
a[2][4] = "West"`

And the function: 

`function state1gmg(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div#gamestatesdiv").text(state1);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div#questionsdiv").text(q[1]);
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#choice1").click(function(){
            $(this).html(a[2][1]);  
        });
    });
}`

Comment: Sorry, I can't troubleshoot code in the comments. Too difficult to read and prone to errors. You should either update this question with code that really shows your problem or start a different question.

Comment: @j08691 Done I just edited the post, hope you can help me.

Comment: @j08691 Omg, I figured it out. It's all my fault. I had to put `for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    a[i] = new Array(4)
}` to put a second Array, but I didn't do it. Thanks for all of your help!!!!!