# Change button text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, button, text

How to change `Text1` and `Text2` to `AnotherText1`, `AnotherText2` with help `jQuery`?

```
<div class="col-md-8">

  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Text1</button>
  </div>                                                                    

  <div class="btn-group pull-left">
     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Text2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the text of a button in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580616/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-button-in-jquery)

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/text

Answer (score 1):

```js
//if you want to change the text only then use 
$("button[type='submit']").text('anything1');
$("button[type='reset']").text('anything2');

//if you want to change the text on click a event then use 
$("button[type='submit']").click(function(e) {
  $(this).text('on click anything1');
});

$("button[type='reset']").click(function(e) {
  $(this).text('on click anything2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-8">

  <div class="btn-group pull-right">
     <button id="btn1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Text1</button>
  </div>                                                                    

  <div class="btn-group pull-left">
     <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">Text2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
<div class="col-md-8">

  <div id="btn1" class="btn-group pull-right">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Text1</button>
  </div>                                                                    

</div>
<script>$('#btn1').text("AnotherText1");</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with .html('AnotherText')

Example:

```
<button type="reset" id="btn1" class="btn btn-warning">Text1</button>

<script> $("#btn1").html('AnotherText1') </script>
```